# What is the identity element in the group (?) of Gaussian distributions under addition?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have come across this concept, but I'm not sure if it is just a monoid. In any event, the random variable resulting from adding up Gaussians is another Gaussian. So there's a set and an binary operation, presumably associative, and closed.

But if $X_1 + X_2 \sim N(\mu_1 + \mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2) $ the only identity element would have to be the degenerate Gaussian with all mass at zero, which would be I assume, a Dirac? And what would be the inverse element?

Comment: $\delta_0$ is the closest thing this semigroup has to an identity element. It isn't in there, but it is arbitrarily well approximated from in there. The sense in the inverse is less apparent: the addition operation is presumably the addition of *independent* Gaussians, which will never reduce the variance.

Comment: You have to be more precise in your formulation as to wheter "Gaussian" refers to the Gaussian distribution or to a random variable whose distribution is a Gaussian distribution. In the first case you actually have to properly define what it means to add distributions, which usually is interpreted as the convolution of the distributions, which corresponds to the distribution achieved by adding independent random variables.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Can you elaborate on the difference? But, yes, convolution is the actual operation to get the distribution of the sum (that part is clear to me).

Comment: There are no inverses.  You'd need a distribution with negative variance, which is impossible.  So it's a semigroup, not a group.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate If $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $X+X \sim N(2\mu, 4 \sigma^2)$, however the convoltion of $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with itself is $N(2\mu,2\sigma^2)$. Also, the set of Gaussian random variables on a probability space is not necessarily closed under addition, which is a nessecary condition in order for it to be a group/semigroup.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen I think the objects here are Gaussian *distributions* and the operation is the distribution of the sum of independent random variables with the associated distributions.

Comment: @Ian Well i think so as well, but that does not guarantee that OP thinks the same.

Comment: @Ian I am trying to sort out what he means [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4031861/878105).