# Difference between "Gaussian distribution" and "random variable whose distribution is a Gaussian distribution."

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The question was a question to me in a comment to a post of mine yesterday [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4030940/878105).

I can't see any difference, and thought that "Gaussian distribution" implicitly meant "distribution [of a random variable]".

I realize this is a soft-question, and if there isn't any substance to the topic, I'll delete it. However, I tend to think there is something I am not aware of, because the user asking me this follow-up question proceeded to tell me that these two concepts would correspond to convolutions $N(2\mu, 4 \sigma^2)$ for the distribution of the sum of two $X,Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$; and $N(2 \mu, 2\sigma^2)$ for $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with itself.

I am not asking for the actual convolutions, but perhaps the set up of the integral, and the difference between both concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probability distribution is a measure on some probability space $\Omega$. Such a probability distribution $\lambda$ takes a subset $A$ of $\Omega$ and assigns a probability
$\lambda(A)$, which is a number between $0$ and $1$. In particular the Gaussian distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the measure defined on $\mathbb{R}$ as
$$\lambda(A):= \int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \: dx.\quad \text{(for $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$)}.$$
A random variable on the other hand, is a function $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega$ is a probability space (or sometimes called sample space), which itself has a probability measure, that we will call $\mathbb{P}$. A random variable $X$ induces a measure $\mathbb{P}_X$ on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by the formula
$$\mathbb{P}_X(A): = \mathbb{P}(X\in A) = \mathbb{P}(\{ \omega \in \Omega \: | \: X(\omega) \in A\}).$$
This measure is called the distribution of $X$ and in particular $X$ has a Gaussian distribution if
$$\mathbb{P}_X(A):= \int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \: dx.$$
It seems to be the case, that you believe that the distribution of $X+Y$ is always the convolution of $\mathbb{P}_X$ with $\mathbb{P}_Y$, but this is wrong, you need to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The point of the example that i commented in your previous post, was that $X$ is usually not independent of $X$ and thus the distribution of $X+X=2X$ is NOT the convolution of $\mathbb{P}_X$ with itself.

To be more explicit the example was: Let $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and let $Y=X$. Then $X+Y = 2X$, and by basic computations we see that $E[2X] = 2\mu$ and $Var(2X) = 4Var(X) = 4 \sigma^2$. Since the sum is Gaussian, we see that $X+Y \sim N(2\mu , 4\sigma^2)$, however if we instead had taken $Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ to be independent of $X$, then $X+Y \sim N(2\mu , 2\sigma^2)$. In both cases we have $X,Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, but the resulting distribution of $X+Y$ is not the same. This is also what i refer to by saying "you actually have to properly define what it means to add distributions".

Comment: That is helpful. I follow well the set theoretical (measurability) concepts behind the notation above (i.e. $\in$ versus $\subset$, sigma algebras, mapping from $\Omega \to \mathbb R$ with measurable pre-images of the Borel sets, etc). And I see the key word that was missing ("independent"), but can you include you splice your current answer with the two convolutions you posted on your comments (reflected above in OP)?

Comment: Also, it would be great if you tied it up with the specific wording that you used in the comment (in the title of the OP), which is still confusing me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious difference is:

- "Gaussian distribution" refers to the distribution
- "a random variable whose distribution is Gaussian" refers to the random variable.

Recall in Kolmogorov's axiomatization of probability theory (which most mathematicians use) one starts with a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and defines

- A distribution is a probability measure $\mathbb{S}$ on some model measure space $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}')$
- A (real-valued) random variable is a measurable function $\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$.

The point @LeanderTilstedKristensen made is that you can obviously add two real-valued functions together, but if you add two probability measures you get a finite measure with total measure $2$ and so not a probability measure.  Hence you will need to define the map "adding distributions"
$$
\mathcal{M}^+_1(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\times\mathcal{M}^+_1(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to\mathcal{M}^+_1(\Omega,\mathcal{F})
$$

Comment: The last paragraph makes it clear. Thank you!

Comment: With regards to your opening statement, the question was whether a "Gaussian distribution" doesn't necessarily imply the existence of a random variable, such that the distribution reflects the probability law induced by the random variable $\Omega \to \mathbb R$ from $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb R)\to (\mathbb R,\mathcal B).$